# Browser information from Apache access

Tags: regex, apache, browser, confluence

Is there a way to get browser information from Apache access log? I can see the user agent info. Did somebody accomplish this using awk, sed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have achieved this using awk and grep from access log.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tomcat Valve Component to Audit your Confluence and get browser information. Take a look at [this document](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/audit-confluence-using-the-tomcat-valve-component-223216846.html) as it contains proper sample logging as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be useful.

https://www.whatismybrowser.com/developers/tools/user-agent-parser/

but, parse user agents api is free until 500 hits.